# linq/ef update (ensure failing update on 1 record does not affect others update)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

im new to linq and c# at work my senior lead reviewed and ask me to ensure that during my update

**" If update is failing for one charge it is not affecting others."**

initially, i added a transaction and she told me not to use a transaction.
How do i accomplish this?

```cs
try
{
    var charge = model.CHARGEs.Where(x => x.MSPCHARGE_ID == 
       (int)item.ChargeId).SingleOrDefault();

    if (charge != null)
    {
        //perform update
        charge.NIBRS_CODE = item.NIBRSCode;
        charge.MOD_DATE = DateTime.Now;
        //save changes
        model.SaveChanges();
        UpdatedCount += 1;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
```

Comment: TBH I don't understand what your team lead wants. You better ask your team lead what exactly is needed.

Comment: It looks like you're only updating only *one* charge anyways. Also, what is wrong with transactions in this case? You should clarify that with her first.